# Does Google Material Design Lite stylesheet covers normalize.css stuff?

Tags: css, material-design, material-design-lite

This is a pretty simple question, but I didn't find any answer neither here, nor in any other place. I'm developing a new project and I will be using the Google Material Design Lite since the beginning.

I'm wondering if using MDL will cause normalize.css no longer needed.

So, here is the question: does Google Material Design Lite stylesheet cover normalize.css stuff?

Comment: short answer: yes they do it their own way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't include normalize.css specifically but as you can see in the source they do their own resets: https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/tree/master/src/resets

Comment: It seems they do pretty simple resets. I wonder if I remove normalize.css from my solution if I'll have too much differences between IE10/11 to Firefox, Chrome etc.

Comment: The new link is https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/tree/mdl-1.x/src/resets

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's normalized. No not by using normalize.css.